# How to use math.sqrt function repeatatively my GUI?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to add the math.sqrt function in my py 2.7 calculator. Here is the function I am using:

```
from Tkinter import *
from math import *

class calculator:
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("Simple Calculator")
        self.display = Entry(master)
        self.display.grid(columnspan = 8, ipadx = 60, ipady = 10)
        Button(master, text = "sqrt", fg = 'white', bg = 'black', 
               command = lambda:self.sqroot(), height =1, width = 10).grid(row = 6, column = 1)

def sqroot(self):
    try:
        self.s=self.display.get()
        self.sqroot=sqrt(eval(self.s))
        self.display.delete(0,END)
        self.display.insert(0,self.sqroot)
    except:
        self.display.delete(0,END)
        self.display.insert(0,'Invalid operation')
```

In the resulting GUI, I can use the 'sqrt' button correctly only once. I am getting the following error message from second time:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: can you point to the line which throws the error? or better post the stack trace

Comment: you shouldn't use `eval` if `self.s` is just a float.Use `float`... and post traceback

Comment: This will be easier to debug if you don't use lambda. Create a proper function so that you can use a debugger or add print statements to examine the values being used by the calculation.

Answer (score 3):

`calculator.sqroot` is, initially, a function (the function that you want).

Then, for the instance of calculator that you're using, you change the function reference `self.sqroot` to a float reference `self.sqroot=sqrt(eval(self.s))`. When you try to call that float reference like it's a function, python gets exception-y.

So don't mask names that you've already used and you'll be fine.

Comment: OP should also avoid `eval` (security reasons)

Answer (score 0):

You can get it work like this. The problem was because `self.sqroot = sqrt(eval(self.s))` changes `self.sqroot` into a string. To the avoid the problem the code below just stores it in a temporary variable named `result`. Also note that you could also do something similar with `self.s` since its value is only needed temporarily inside the method.

**Note** I also modified your code so it conforms more to the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines.

```
from Tkinter import *
from math import *

class calculator:
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("Simple Calculator")
        self.display = Entry(master)
        self.display.grid(columnspan=8, ipadx=60, ipady=10)
        Button(master, text="sqrt", fg='white', bg='black',
               command=lambda: self.sqroot(), height=1, width=10).grid(row=6, column=1)

    def sqroot(self):
        try:
            self.s = self.display.get()
#            self.sqroot = sqrt(eval(self.s))
            result = sqrt(eval(self.s))
            self.display.delete(0, END)
#            self.display.insert(0, self.sqroot)
            self.display.insert(0, result)
        except:
            self.display.delete(0, END)
            self.display.insert(0, 'Invalid operation')

root = Tk()
calculator(root)
root.mainloop()
```